# Install libevent man pages from sourcecode with autotools

Tags: c, debian, autotools, manpage, libevent

I've installed libevent from source code (from the git repository) with autotools.
I thought the command 'make install-man' would install the man pages, but nothing is available. I've also tried setting the './configuration --datadir' option without results.

How can I install libevent man pages?

Comment: No man pages in https://github.com/libevent/libevent . No man pages in Debian libevent https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libevent-2.1 ...... *On-line*  **man libevent** etc. https://www.google.com/search?q=man+libevent

Comment: Ubuntu libevent1-dev https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libevent1-dev/filelist provides two of the 804 libevent man pages ( included in Mageia, PCLinuxOS ) https://drive.google.com/file/d/13xvl9bxpRqN8B48W2NzafkEaN58TxPxd/view?usp=sharing .... Ref. lib64event-devel http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/Linux/distr/pclinuxos/pclinuxos/apt/pclinuxos/64bit/RPMS.x86_64/lib64event-devel-2.1.11-3pclos2020.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've installed libevent from source code (from the git repository)
> with autotools. I thought the command 'make install-man' would install
> the man pages, but nothing is available.

In an Automake-based build system such as you are using, `make install` will install man pages along with everything else, and `make install-man` will install the man pages alone ... PROVIDED THAT there are any.

From examination of the libevent source, it appears that libevent does not provide man pages by default, but that you can turn on their generation and installation at `configure` time.

> I've also tried setting the
> './configuration --datadir' option without results.
>
> How can I install libevent man pages?

Run `./configure --help` to see a summary of all the available options (I recommend doing this before building any Autotools project).  I think you will see `--enable-doxygen-man` among the available options, and I expect that turning this on when you (re)configure will cause man pages to be generated during the build and installed during the installation.  If you're sufficiently clever then you can probably work out how to build and install just those, but the easiest way forward proceeds via rebuilding the whole project.

Comment: This solved it! To complete the solution:
reconfigured the package with `./configure --enable-doxygen-doc --enable-doxygen-man` and installed man pages with `make install-man`